# `ModuleWithProviders` - Is it require while I move `routes` in to seperate file?

Tags: angular

I seen in one of the tutorial, while I move my `routes` file separated, then I should include the `ModuleWithProviders` to the file. But even without this, all this works.

Is this required really? or still `angular5` requires this? any one help me to understand the `ModuleWithProviders` correctly?

here is my separated `router.js` file:

```
import {RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import {ModuleWithProviders} from "@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module";
import { CalcComponent } from './calc/calc.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';

export const AppRoutes:Routes = [
    {path:"calc",component:CalcComponent},
    {path:"",component:HomeComponent},
    {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

export const ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes);
```

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

ModuleWithProviders is the interface that is supposed to be returned by forRoot method. ModuleWithProviders object is plain object that has ngModule property that contains actual module class augmented with additional providers in providers property.

Since ModuleWithProviders is an interface, its usage is optional.

Comment: So can I ignore to add in to my file ( see my code )?

Answer (score 0):

ModuleWithProviders does not get imported to the Main app routing file (the main app is already providing services), add to the lazy modules you create.

app-routing.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
// views
import { NotFoundComponent } from '@sp-views/errors/not-found/not-found.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [

   { path: '', loadChildren: '@sp-views/content/content.module#ContentModule' },
   { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
          appRoutes,
        )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

content-routing.ts

Content Module (lazy loaded so needs ModuleWithProviders, to provide the services for the module content)

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const ContentRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '',
         loadChildren: '@sp-views/content/content.module#ContentModule',

    },

];

export const ContentRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ContentRoutes);
```